# Run a 5K and a 4K monitor via a Thunderbolt 4 hub without DSC

Tags: usb, display, multiple-monitors, displayport, thunderbolt

My question is rather simple. I am wondering if I can run a 5K display (LG UltraFine 5K) and a 4K display (Dell U2720Q) using a Thunderbolt 4 hub (something like CalDigit's Thunderbolt 4 Element) on a 16" M1 Max MacBook Pro 2021 (using a single cable to the laptop). Currently, I am running two of the aforementioned 4K displays over a Dell WD19TB dock (which as far as I know is Thunderbolt 3) without a problem at their native resolution and refresh rate.

As far as I know, both the 5K and the 4K display do not support DSC, so I am not sure if the bandwidth is enough for the configuration. If I need to drop to USB 2 for the peripherals, that would be fine for me, as long as I can run both displays at their native resolution with 60Hz.

I appreciate any insight into these rather convoluted specifications.

Comment: After further research it seems that the displays do not need to support DSC, as the adapters will decode the DSC, so the display does not even see it. I just tried the mentioned configuration and out of the box the 5K display will switch to 4K60. It seems like it would only work with DSC, but I haven't figured out yet, if the CalDigit dock supports that.